# play framework: sbt run vs play run

Tags: command-line, playframework, sbt

What is the difference between command:

```
sbt run
```

and

```
play run
```

I am using starter java project:
[play-java-starter-example](https://example.lightbend.com/v1/download/play-java-starter-example)

Answer (score 1):

play framework projects used "activator" to run application
https://www.lightbend.com/community/core-tools/activator-and-sbt

But "activator" is dead on May 24, 2017. Old activator project templates are recommend to migrate to "giter8" templates.

You should to use "sbt" instead of "activator" now.